# Facebook login IE - error on page - all.js - (Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL...) & redirect

Tags: facebook, authentication

i have a problem, after succesfull user login i want to redirect user to some page (depending where he came from etc...). Prior one week everything was working ok, but now it doesnt want to redirect in IE, but it redirects in chrome or FF. 
I think it is becouse there is an javascript error in facebook all.js, and then the redirect doesnt excecute in IE. Im i wrong?

i have a common facebook login button:

Login...

Javascript (when succes i want to redirect page - that is the problem!!!)

```
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId   : '12345',
        session : null, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
        status  : true, // check login status
        cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
    });

    // whenever the user logs in, we redirect the page
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
          window.parent.location="MY URL";
      }
    });
    };

  (function() {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.type = 'text/javascript';
      e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      e.async = true;
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
```

So when user clicks the login button, i got the following error: Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL .... Domains, protocols and ports must match. (checked in chrome). In IE i get: permission denied, all.js (http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js).

I tried to add header P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA", but it doesnt help (checked with http://web-sniffer.net/ that the header is there!).

what can i do now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the channelUrl in the init method but you have to take care that the url is https or http in accordance with your app. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/530/
That could solve the unsafe access problems.